# word2vec CBOW reader implementation on CNTK

Tags: python, word2vec, cntk

I want to implement CBOW word2vec with negative sampling. I read through the documentation of CNTK but couldn't find a reader which could take sentences as input and output `2*k + 1` words (current word and `k` context words to the left and right of current word). Also, I'm want to implement this in python.

Is there any guide to create a custom cntk text reader in python?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a community contributed CNTK model for word2vec. https://github.com/jatinarora2702/CNTK-Word2Vec

You can leverage some of the code here to model your reader. You are very welcome to contribute it back to the toolkit.

Comment: There are multiple problems with this implementation. First, it reads all the sentences in a single array. Second, I creates a one hot-vector encoding of the input words and outputs a softmax on entire vocabulary which will fail miserably in case of huge vocabulary. Also, its not a CBOW implementation. But, I got some hints for creating the reader. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. If you want to contribute a CBOW implementation we would be happy to take it in.